# Pivot_wider keeps length of original data frame

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to reshape a long data frame that consists of 40 years of daily data for 11 stations.  The data frame has each 40 year block concatenated together.  Each station has the following data:

```
date    datatype station               value fl_m   fl_q    fl_so   fl_t
1/1/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120784   396         0   700
1/2/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120784   66          0   700
1/3/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120784   3           0   700
1/4/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120784   0           0   700
1/5/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120784   13          0   700
1/6/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120784   25          0   700
1/7/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120784   64          0   700
1/8/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120784   30          0   700
1/9/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120784   0           0   700
```

The station column has 11 unique values for each site.  The date column range is 1/1/1979 to 12/31/2019.

When I pivot_wider:

```
fin <- pivot_wider(data= fin, names_from = station, values_from = value )
```

it works in that it reshapes to 11 unique stations to the columns, but each date, for each station, is still in the data frame so that I have the same number of rows and NAs.  Does the date have to be unique to each station?

I apologize in advance for a poorly presented or worded question.  This is my first time and I'm new to R.  Thank you.

First two days of 1979 for two stations:

```
Row     date       datatype station            value fl_m   fl_q  fl_so fl_t
1       1/1/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120784   396               0 700
2       1/2/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120784   66                0 700
14765   1/1/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120877   386               0 700
14766   1/2/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00120877   56                0 700
29490   1/1/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00123082   15                0 2400
29491   1/2/1979    PRCP    GHCND:USC00123082   13                0 2400
```

Comment: You may need to create a sequence column by group

Comment: Can you explain what the `fl_` columns are? Are they variables? You could try just providing a data sample with all stations but only a few days of data so we can understand the structure better. This sample makes it seem like there are multiple measurements of different variables at each station on each day (PRCP, the `fl_` columns)

Comment: The fl columns are flags.  fl_m and fl_q are blank.  But yes, there is more than PRCP reported each day.  I will try to provide a better example.  Thank you!

Comment: Re: sequence column by group, add a unique identifier to each station?  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Row         date        datatype station                        value   fl_m fl_q  fl_so fl_t
1       1/1/1979 PRCP GHCND:USC00120784 396         0 700
2         1/2/1979 PRCP GHCND:USC00120784 66         0 700
14765 1/1/1979 PRCP GHCND:USC00120877 386         0 700
14766 1/2/1979 PRCP GHCND:USC00120877 56         0 700
29490 1/1/1979 PRCP GHCND:USC00123082 15         0 2400
29491 1/2/1979 PRCP GHCND:USC00123082 13         0 2400

Comment: I apologize the formatting is not cooperating ....

Comment: `dput(head(x))` is a great way to share data unambiguously. It also helps mitigate problems like empty columns, as it makes your current data more difficult for use to magically parse into R.

Comment: Thanks!  structure(list(X = 1:6, date = c("1979-01-01", "1979-01-02", 
"1979-01-03", "1979-01-04", "1979-01-05", "1979-01-06"), datatype = c("PRCP", 
"PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP", "PRCP"), station = c("GHCND:USC00120784", 
"GHCND:USC00120784", "GHCND:USC00120784", "GHCND:USC00120784", 
"GHCND:USC00120784", "GHCND:USC00120784"), value = c(396L, 66L, 
3L, 0L, 13L, 25L), fl_m = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), fl_q = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), fl_so = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
    fl_t = c(700L, 700L, 700L, 700L, 700L, 700L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Can you show what would be your expected output for the data shared?

Comment: Hi all, I got this to work simply by eliminating the columns I don't care about.  So it was only date, station, and value.  Then I did: fin <- pivot_wider(data= fin, names_from = station, values_from = value ) and it worked magically.  Thanks for putting up with my disastrous first post :)